# RSA decryption coming out backwards, Javascript -> perl

Tags: javascript, perl, cryptography, rsa, endianness

I am attempting to take a password from a form, encrypt it with RSA in java script and submit the form.

When the Form is received by the Perl code, it will then decrypt the password. I've been able to get the java script and the Perl using the same RSA key, and i can decrypt messages encrypted in java script with java script, and messages encrypted in Perl with Perl.

The next step is to encrypt in java script and decrypt in Perl. After a lot of frusteration i'm almost there, however the decrypted string is backwards:

```
Clear Text Here!
```

Gets encrypted in Javascript then submitted via post
Perl then attempts to decrypt and the following is created

```
������������������������������������������������ereh txet raelC
```

As you can see, it's backwards. The weird characters are a result of the javascript library padding out the string with 0's.

I suspect this may have to do with endianness but my experiments to that end so far create gobbly-gook.

I'm using the perl package Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
And the javascript rsa and related math libraries written by Dave Shapiro found here: http://ohdave.com/rsa/

The javascript RSA library returns it's value as a decimal representation of the binary. I feed this to a Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum object to convert it back into binary for the perl code to use.

The encryption code is:

```
function doEncryption(key, ptextID, ctextID) {
  $(ctextID).val("Encrypting...");
  $(ctextID).val(encryptedString(key, $(ptextID).val()));
}
```

And the decryption code is:

```
sub java_decrypt {
  my $message = shift;
  my $rsa = shift;

    $rsa->use_no_padding();
    my @blocks = split ' ', $message;
    my $decmessage = "";
    foreach my $block (@blocks) {
      my $bitz = Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_decimal($block);
      $decmessage .= $rsa->decrypt($bitz->to_bin());
    }
    $rsa->use_pkcs1_oaep_padding();
    #$decmessage = reverse $decmessage;
    #$decmessage =~ s/\0//g;
    return($decmessage);
}
```

The two lines commented out at the end will correct the issues with the decryption being backwards and padded, but I don't know that i trust it. If encrypted in perl, it comes out the correct way, so if there is a better way to solve this (switch the endianness of the binary string?) I would much prefer that.

I've tried to swap the endianness with pack, but this has only rewarded me with gibberish. And just in case it's asked, the string concatenation of the decrypted message does not come into play, as the message is in a single 64byte block currently.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? An attacker who wants the password could simply modify the javascript you send the client to cause the password to be sent in plaintext - or intercept the key, so they can read the encrypted password.

Comment: RSA, I can give the javascript ONLY the public portion of the key, thus if they intercept them it does them no good because they need the private key which is safe on the server. I am assuming that an attacker can only intercept the transmission. I'm not sure of how to protect users against modifed javascript, but an attack on the clients computer will always work as you can set the javascript to key log as they type their password. Otherwise you're advocating always using plaintext password transmission, as any kind of protection is useless, with which i will disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a compelling reason not to just use a simple hashing algorithm like sha256 encrypt the whole session via TLS (SSL) rather than attempting to do something overly complex with RSA at this level?

Also, I have only a passing familiarity with Javascript, but I'm pretty sure it's returning a hex value, not a decimal.  are you absolutely sure it's decimal?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you're correct, it'd be better to just hash the password and submit it w/o decyption, but i have to mate it to an LDAP system that will only accept cleartext passwords.

Comment: `var text = key.radix == 16 ? biToHex(crypt) : biToString(crypt, key.radix);`    Source
vs.
`var text = key.radix == 16 ? biToDecimal(crypt) : biToString(crypt, key.radix);`    Mine

Interesting! My RSA library conflicts with the source. As you can see, it's SUPPOSED to output in hex, but the code calls binToDecimal. I checked the source on the authors page and this is not the case. I'll try updating my source and see if anything changes